# include tracking number in emails subject part

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

As we send shippment emails to customers, in this shippment email, we get tracking number from track.phtml and now the subject part of the email is like, order number and shippment number. I would like to change the subject of the email in which we are senidng as shippment emails. The subject has to be with tracking number. For order number we can get with "order.increment_id", But I dont know how to get the tracking number. SO how can I display tracking number in subject of email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done only by using a variable name like "order.increment_id" in the email template. You have to send the tracking data to the email template processor to achieve this with an example in 4 steps.

**Step1>> Add Module configuration**
In app/etc/modules/Eglobe_Sales.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eglobe_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Eglobe_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step2>> Add config.xml(app/code/local/Eglobe/Sales/etc/config.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eglobe_Sales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Eglobe_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
            <order_shipment>Eglobe_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment</order_shipment>
        </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step3>> Override Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment::sendEmail()**

```
     <?php

class Eglobe_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment {

    /**
     * Send email with shipment data
     *
     * @param boolean $notifyCustomer
     * @param string $comment
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment
     */
    public function sendEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '')
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();

        if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewShipmentEmail($storeId)) {
            return $this;
        }
        // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
        $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
        $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);
        // Check if at least one recepient is found
        if (!$notifyCustomer && !$copyTo) {
            return $this;
        }

        // Start store emulation process
        $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
        $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

        try {
            // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
            $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
                    ->setIsSecureMode(true);
            $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
            $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            // Stop store emulation process
            $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
            throw $exception;
        }

        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

        // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
        if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
        }

        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        if ($notifyCustomer) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
            if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
                // Add bcc to customer email
                foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                    $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
                }
            }
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }

        // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy' or a customer should not be notified
        if ($copyTo && ($copyMethod == 'copy' || !$notifyCustomer)) {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                $emailInfo->addTo($email);
                $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
            }
        }

        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order' => $order,
            'shipment' => $this,
            'comment' => $comment,
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
//setting the `track number here, A shihpment can have more than one track numbers so seperating by comma`
            'tracks' => new Varien_Object(array('tracking_number' => implode(',', $this->getTrackingNumbers())))
                )
        );
        $mailer->send();

        return $this;
    }

    //Creating track number array
    public function getTrackingNumbers()
    {
        $tracks = $this->getAllTracks();
        $trackingNumbers = array();
        if (count($tracks)) {
            foreach ($tracks as $track) {
                $trackingNumbers[] = $track->getNumber();
            }
        }
        return $trackingNumbers;
    }

}
```

**Step4>> Modify your shipment email tempate subject by adding {{var tracks.track_number}}**

Comment: I have followed all the steps. But it didnt show any tracking number in subject of email.. Are we missing any where?

Comment: @Johngrews confirm the following...
**1>>** No other modules rewriting the class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment (simply search the "code" directory for "order_shipment"). If you find any match like below code, let me know
`<sales>
                <rewrite>
            <order_shipment>Some_Class_Name_Here</order_shipment>
        </rewrite>
            </sales>`
**2>>** You flushed your magento cache.
**3>>** You edited the correct template. There may be a chance to modify the wrong template. If you edited the template file in the app/locale/your_locale/template/email/sales/shipment_new.html..

Comment: @Johngrews continuation of previous msg...
please make sure you have no template copy in database.. If you have one, edit the subject of that template.

Comment: no..  I have checked as suggested, But no use. I dont maintain any copy of email template in database

Comment: @Johngrews, Only thing I could find is the "class" keyword was missing in the code. I have updated the code used in **Step3**. To make sure the class is overriding the core class, try putting below code at the end of index.php.

`echo get_class(Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment'));` If it is printing "Eglobe_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment", eveything should work.

I would like to know which template file you have edited and how?

Comment: I have placed "class" keyword in step3 previously. The index.php returns the class name as "Eglobe_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment" at the bottom of the page. I am modifying the template of Shipment_new_guest.phtml as I am testing through logging in as guest.

Comment: I am editing the Shipment_new_guest.html file in the path of app/local/en_US/template/email/sales. Here the subjected I edited as <!--@subject {{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Track #{{var tracks.track_number}} for Shipment # {{var shipment.increment_id}} for Order # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->

Comment: Check your logs for any errors related to this. It's working fine on my machine. Not sure what went wrong!!!

Confirm the template name by putting a die or by logging `$templateId`

Comment: @johngrews any luck??

Comment: I am so thank u for your help that you had done. I didnt get the result as required. So I created another template as track_subject.phtml which is similar to track.phtml and I tried to call that track_subject.phtml in the subject part of the email template file. Now it displays the tracking number in subject part. I am not sure this is fine or not. But i think this is also a correct approach.. :)

Comment: @johngrews Happy to hear that you got a solution, but sad to hear this post didn't help you :(.

Cheers...

Comment: As this solution works in ur machine, I am accepting this answer, because it may helps others also...